# How can update a flow file attribute value data type (String to byte) in the NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using NiFi version 1.8.0.3.3.0.0-165, and not getting an idea for converting an attribute value data type (String to byte).

Is it possible to convert the data type of NiFi flow file attribute.

Answer (score 0):

for attributes you can use this guide
[Apache NiFi Expression Language Guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html)
if you don't find the solution you can use a groovy script to load your attribute and do whatever you want

```
def flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile) return
    
    def val = flowFile.getAttribute('yourattribue')
    //mod your val 
    flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'yourattributeout', yourattributeout)
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

Comment: I tried the below script :try {
   def flowFile = session.get()
    if(!flowFile) return

    def val= flowFile.getAttribute('mqtt-topic')
    def valbyte=val.getBytes()
//Set the session values start 
    //def attrMap = ['status_desc':val.getBytes(), 'status_code':'test']
    flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "mqtt-topic",valbyte)
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
} catch (e){
    log.error('Scripting error', e)
    flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "error", e.getMessage())
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
}

Comment: Here also Error,  I think Attribute only supported <String,String> type, it's not working with <String,bytes []>

Comment: you can put your byte array inside the flowfile if you don't need it

Comment: Actually this attribute we are using to send as Kafka header with help with PublishKafka_1_0 Processor, So we need changes in an Attribute value only. Is there any way to send Kafka header in bytes without changes in attribute?